# C# Visual Studio 2012 'Find all References' and 'Refactor' missing some references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

**Background**

Visual Studio 2012, solution with 3 C# projects (all targeting .NET 4.5), all projects build and run without error, 'Find all references' and refactoring was working fine yesterday.

**Bug**

Refactoring missed several references to method and type names. 'Find all references' is failing to find some references to a method or type in the active project.

**Already Tried**

Closed Visual Studio, deleted all generated files, opened and rebuilt, reset all options, rebooted Winbloze and repeated. Hunted through past complaints about this problem and checked everything I could find...

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See if this is of any help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0f99d9f-31ef-42bd-8f33-b3dd8e7e1de8/find-all-references-and-go-to-definition-do-not-work?forum=vbide . It says that the projects could be targeting there versions of .net runtime.

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692694/go-to-definition-find-all-references-do-not-work-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep, already checked both of those. All projects target 4.5, and included libraries are compatible All project components are 'normal' without any 'dotted boxes'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go to definition & Find all references do not work in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692694/go-to-definition-find-all-references-do-not-work-in-visual-studio)